# Drawing a UIImage using CoreGraphics that uses capInsets to grow the image

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, cgimage, xcasset

Assume I have an image stored in Images.xcassets that is sliced; ie its `capInsets` property is set and I want to draw that image larger than its actual size in CoreGraphics. How do I do this?

Do I have to use the `capInsets` property to manually slice the image in to 9 parts and then grow/stretch the 9 parts manually or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(litView.layer.frame.size);
    [litImg drawInRect:litView.layer.frame];
    UIImage *resizedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Please don't just have a block of code, add some explanation why it's correct.

Comment: It would appear that @jenVM is suggesting that it will automatically draw correctly based on the cap insets. Before you accept the answer, you will probably want to check and make sure it works.

Comment: Also you must check for scale parameter:


    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
                     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(litView.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen  mainScreen] scale]);

    } else { 
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(litView.frame.size);
    }